# Diff python files, ignoring line ending styles, indentation styles and trailing spaces

Tags: python, diff

**TL-DR**: *Get 'functionally' diff of two python files*

I'm writing a plugin framework which will run on unix, mac and windows.
For one part, I need to check, if files in two folders are functionally equal python code, in order to remove redundancies.
Now I know that "will file a run with the same results as file b" is both a tough and a stupid question.
What I want instead is to check wether file a and file b contain the same code, while ignoring:

- different line-ending styles (windows "\r\n" vs unix "\n" vs mac "\r")
- trailing whitespaces
- different indentation styles (tabulator vs spaces, 2-spaces vs 4-spaces, etc.)

and if possible:

- differing blank lines
- inner indentations (e.g. indentation in a multi-line list)
- funky indentations (mixing indentation styles, e.g. 2 spaces for the first level but 6 spaces for the second one)

I would prefer it if a diff-representation would be returned, but a "mismatch"-info and the first mismatch line number would be sufficient. If external utilities are used, they need to be standard on the respective systems, or free, lightweight and portable (so I can include them in my portable framework).

currently I'm running this on python 3:

```
##  test if two files are the same (spare for line-endings)
def cmp_lines(path_1, path_2, skip_blanklines=True, skip_trailing=True, skip_leading=False, spaces_per_tab=4, comp_indent=False):
    l1 = l2 = True
    with open(path_1, 'rU') as f1, open(path_2, 'rU') as f2:
        ind1, ind2 = [0],[0]
        while l1 and l2:
            l1 = f1.readline()
            l2 = f2.readline()
            # ueberarbeiten: trailing whitespaces entfernen.
            if skip_trailing: l1, l2 = l1.rstrip(), l2.rstrip()
            # indentation testen (entfernt auch leading-whitespaces)
            #-  hier werden unter-indentierungen zb in mehrzeiligen listen
            #-  als normale indentierungen behandelt
            if comp_indent:
                l1b, l2b = l1.lstrip(), l2.lstrip()
                i1, i2 = l1[:len(l1)-len(l1b)], l2[:len(l2)-len(l2b)]
                ind1b = len(i1)*[1, spaces_per_tab][i1=="\t"*len(i1)]
                ind2b = len(i2)*[1, spaces_per_tab][i2=="\t"*len(i2)]
                while ind1b < ind1[-1]: ind1.pop()
                while ind2b < ind2[-1]: ind2.pop()
                if ind1[-1]<ind1b: ind1.append(ind1b)
                if ind2[-1]<ind2b: ind2.append(ind2b)
                if len(ind1)!=len(ind2): print("indentation missmatch")
                l1, l2 = l1b, l2b
            # ueberarbeiten: leading whitespaces entfernen.
            elif skip_leading: l1, l2 = l1.lstrip(), l2.lstrip()
            if l1 != l2:
                #print('a',l1,'-a',l1=='',l1=='\n',l1=='\r\n',l1=='\r')
                #print('b',l2,'-b',l2=='',l2=='\n',l2=='\r\n',l2=='\r')
                if skip_blanklines: # ueberarbeiten. kann bisher nur einen skip
                    if l1 == '\n':
                        l1b=f1.readline()
                        if l1b==l2: continue
                    if l2 == '\n':
                        l2b=f2.readline()
                        if l2b==l1: continue
                return False
    return True
```

These two codes should be equal (with \t for tab, \r for CR and \n for LF)

```
if True:  \r\n
    \n
    print('HI')\r
```

```
if True:\n
\tprint('HI')\n
```

Comment: I'd probably recommend looking at the bytecode or actual AST of the source, using the builtin `dis` or `ast` modules, rather than comparing the text of the source itself. There are existing tools for more robust analysis of the AST, see [here](https://greentreesnakes.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) for lots of useful resources.

Comment: @bnaecker Thanks. I'll look into it tomorrow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Get 'functionally' diff of two python files

As I see it, there is no way to do that beside parsing python.
The reason is that sometimes spaces matter and sometimes they don't. It depends on context, and you cannot know context if you don't parse.

For instance, there is a "functional" difference between :

```
a_string = """foo
bar"""
```

and

```
a_string = """foo
     bar"""
```

despite the fact it just is an indentation difference

Parsing should probably not be done by yourself. You may want to embed an already existing python parser. But it may be a lot of work.

If parsing is not an option for you, you may want to use a degraded version of comparison that doesn't care about spaces at all (something that behave like diff -w). Here is my attempt :

```
from collections import OrderedDict

class no_space_file_reader :
    def __init__(self, filepath):
        self.file = open(filepath)

    def all_chars(self):
        last_is_space = False
        for line in self.file.readlines():
            for char in line:
                if char in " \t\r\n":
                    if last_is_space :
                        continue
                    else:
                        last_is_space = True
                else :
                    last_is_space = False
                    yield char

a = no_space_file_reader("a.txt")
b = no_space_file_reader("b.txt")
for c_a,c_b in zip(a.all_chars(), b.all_chars()):
    if c_a != c_b:
       print("diff")
```

of course it will not see any differences between

```
a_string = m("")
```

and

```
a_string = m(" ")
```

which is uncool. But that's the price for not parsing.

> I would prefer it if a diff-representation would be returned

It's also tricky. But at lease feasible. Here is my full attempt :

```
from collections import OrderedDict

class no_space_file_reader :
    def __init__(self, filepath):
        self.file = open(filepath)
        self.context_size = 2
        self.context = OrderedDict()

    def all_chars(self):
        last_was_space = False
        for lineid,line in enumerate(self.file.readlines()):
            self.context[lineid] = line.strip()
            if len(self.context) > self.context_size:
                self.context.popitem(last=False)
            for char in line:
                if char in " \t\r\n":
                    if last_was_space :
                        continue
                    else:
                        last_was_space = True
                else :
                    last_was_space = False
                    yield char

class diff_agglomerator :
    def __init__(self):
        self.diff = [{},{}]
        self.context_size = 2

    def append(self, contexts):
        self.diff[0].update(contexts[0])
        self.diff[1].update(contexts[1])

    def pop_and_format_diff_if_ended(self, current_lines):
        if self.is_empty():
            return ""
        last_lines = [max(self.diff[0].keys()), max(self.diff[1].keys())]
        toReturn =""
        if last_lines[0] < current_lines[0] - self.context_size and \
           last_lines[1] < current_lines[1] - self.context_size:
              toReturn = self.pop_and_format_diff()
        return toReturn

    def format_line(self, a_dict):
        return "\n".join(["{} :{}".format(k,v) for k,v in a_dict])

    def pop_and_format_diff(self):
        toReturn = ">"*5 + "\n"
        toReturn += self.format_line(self.diff[0].items()) + "\n"
        toReturn += "="*5 + "\n"
        toReturn += self.format_line(self.diff[1].items()) + "\n"
        toReturn += "<"*5 + "\n"
        self.diff = [{},{}]
        return toReturn

    def is_empty(self):
        return len(self.diff[0]) == 0 and len (self.diff[1]) == 0

def print_if_non_empty(a_string):
    if len(a_string)>0:
        print(a_string)
        
a = no_space_file_reader("a.txt")
b = no_space_file_reader("b.txt")

diff = diff_agglomerator()
for c_a,c_b in zip(a.all_chars(), b.all_chars()):
    print(c_a,c_b)
    if c_a != c_b:
        diff.append([a.context, b.context])
    else:
        first_context_lines = [min(a.context.keys()), min(b.context.keys())]
        print_if_non_empty(diff.pop_and_format_diff_if_ended(first_context_lines))
print_if_non_empty(diff.pop_and_format_diff())
```

It produces that kind of result :

```
>>>>>
4 :
5 :foo
6 :bar
=====
3 :
4 :bar  foo
<<<<<

>>>>>
18 :
19 :foo
20 :bar
=====
16 :
17 :bar foo
<<<<<
```

Comment: Better impossibility illustration : "(a, b)" is equivalent to "(a,b)" but "foo()" is not equivalent to "fo o()"

Comment: True, but I don't want to clear inner whitespaces, I just want to clear trailing whitespaces and indentations. I can clear leading and trailing whitespaces with lstrip and rstrip, but I want to know, if the indentation changed... Anyways, I'll take a closer look at your code tomorrow.